# Returning to moderation

Tags: discussion

I've been giving a lot of thought to the question of resignation over the weekend, and one thing that kept going through my head was Jon Ericson's [blog post](http://jlericson.com/2020/01/17/leaving_stack.html). Despite what he had to say about differences with leadership about healthy community management, what stuck with me was Jon's hope that the company could learn how to work with the community and his [desire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342424/228367) to become a moderator again.

Things are pretty bad right now, but toward the end of last week I saw some signs that communication between the community and leadership is not completely severed, if strained. It's not going on through the usual channels, but it's still there and feedback is still being heard to some extent. As I thought about this and what Jon said about having hope, it was hard to deny that it looked like there was still a chance to salvage things, and I think the best way to keep those lines of communication open is to stay on as a mod.

No matter what the future has in store for us, here at Astronomy we have a great community *now*, and things here have been scarcely impacted by the network drama. I want to continue to support *this* vibrant community as long as I can. Thank you for all the support in response to my leave of absence post! I look forward to resuming work with all of you.

Comment: My suggestion would be: don't consider, how the company behaves today. Consider, how will they behave, after the storm runs out. It still might be a reason to come back, but... I think there is no reason of any hope, contrary what Jon and the others said.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Whatever the prospects of hope are, this community is still here, and I still have interest in supporting it.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica I mean, you still do things around here. If there's no reason to stick around, why are you?

Comment: Yes, that is acceptable, only the worth of the diamond is reduced hugely (and of the rep-bound privileges, too). You might have also the reason, that returning as a mod decreases the expected value of the count of the future mods, actually enjoying the (censored) what is coming on, by 1. Furthermore, resignation is imho a very ineffective way to protest, compared to the alternatives.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Everyone has to weigh for themselves what the best course of action is. I've decided that for now the best way I can ensure a good future for mods and the community is to stay engaged.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103566/discussion-on-question-by-called2voyage-returning-to-moderation).

Comment: FYI to CMs - Jon's name is included here with explicit permission: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53506087#53506087

Answer (score 5):

No one has said it yet, so I will.

Thank you, called2voyage,  for your past and now continuing service to the Astronomy and Space Exploration communities.